# My PC won't boot after I format my HDD. I have a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu on the SSD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, ssd, grub

Ok, so here is what happening. First, I had Windows and Ubuntu in the HDD. Then, I installed the SSD and installed both Windows and Ubuntu there too. Everything was working just fine (and the time to boot in both OS are less than 5 seconds). Yesterday, I formatted my HD (since I thought I dont needed it anymore). But when I restarted my PC, it went straight to the BIOS.

It seens I couldn't boot in the UEFI mode at all, so I turned CSM mode ON, and then I could see both my HD and SDD when I booted. But when I tried to start from the SDD, it didn't find any bootloader.

I have a pen drive with ubuntu and windows 11 installation. I plugged the ubuntu one, and manage to run the boot-repair. The boot repair said that I dont have a partition with a bios_flag setted on, so I created one in the SSD using gparted. Ok, now the boot-repair worked and installed the grub. but I couldn't get into Windows and I couldn't even turn off the CSM mode (apart from the boot time now being around 3 minutes).

So I went to the windows 11 USB.

The repair doesn't work, so I've tried some tutorials on the CMD. I tried to use bootrec but it doesn't work. I've also created a new partition (with 500MB!) on the SSD using diskpart but when I try to move the boot files to there it says It can't do the operation.

So I went to boot repair on ubuntu again, and installed the grub in the partition I've created on the diskpart. It worked a little bit (I guess), since now I can turn CSM off and can see ubuntu and windows when I boot. But when I choose to boot from Windows, it starts the ubuntu GRUB (without windows in it!). Summorizing the problem:

1. I cant start Windows 10
2. Ubuntu takes 3 minutes or so to boot
3. I have two grubs (one in the ubuntu partition and other in the 500mb partition I've created in diskpart)

PS:. When I run boot-repair, it says my Windows is LegacyWindows, but I don't know if thats true (I think not, but I also don't know exactly what is LegacyWindows).

Edit 1: Here's the fdisk -l command:

```
Dispositivo    Início       Fim   Setores Tamanho Tipo
/dev/sdb1        2048 478515199 478513152  228,2G Linux sistema de arquivos
/dev/sdb2   478515200 488280063   9764864    4,7G Linux swap
/dev/sdb3   488280064 488312831     32768     16M Microsoft reservado
/dev/sdb4   488312832 974669823 486356992  231,9G Microsoft dados básico
/dev/sdb5   974669824 975693823   1024000    500M Sistema EFI
/dev/sdb6   975693824 976771071   1077248    526M Windows ambiente de recuperaçã
/dev/sdb7   976771072 976773119      2048      1M BIOS inicialização
```

Comment: You probably nuked your EFI partition. Legacy Windows is referring to MBR instead of UEFI.  However, without confirmation that you installed Windows with Legacy Mode enabled/disabled originally it will be impossible to answer your question. I am guessing EFI partition was deleted because that’s the default mode in all OEM sold equipment. **It’s also required for Windows 11.** Windows 11 doesn’t support MBR

Comment: How can I check if I've installed Windows with Legacy mode enabled or disabled? When I was using the windows in the SSD (before the HDD format) I didn't have CRM enabled

Comment: Impossible at this point since you formatted the HDD.

Comment: When I was using the windows in the SSD (before the HDD format) I didn't have CRM enabled. And it worked just fine

Comment: Do you mean CSM I have no idea what CRM is, CSM is also known as Legacy or Compatibility Mode. *CRM isn’t a thing* If you didn’t have it enabled it means it was disabled.

Comment: Yes, CSM. I'm sorry for the confusion. And I was using Windows 11 in the SSD (I've remembered that I updated)

Comment: @LuizF.Couto Add to your post **fdisk -l** command output. In case of you don't manage accessing Ubuntu, so try with bootable Ubuntu usb-stick for running the informed command.